# setting two queues in torque?

Tags: debugging, cluster-computing, cpu-usage, pbs, torque

I have one queue called "batch" in a torque setup. I want to create a new queue 
called "db" for debugging jobs. "db" queue will have several restrictions such as
maximum CPU time of 10 min, etc. Both queues would use the same nodes in principle.
I can create the new queue with the command "qmgr" there is not problem with that.

My question is, would there 
be any issue if both queues are using the same nodes? I don't know if there could be
intereference between two processes comming from different queues.
Usually what I observe in 
supercomputers is that they use different nodes for different queues, but in our
case we have only a small cluster and it doesn't make sense to share resources 
between queues.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that should be fine:

If you don't specify which nodes belong to which queue, then all queues apply to all nodes.

```
qmgr 
create queue db
set queue db resources_default.walltime=00:10:00
set queue db queue_type = Execution
set queue enabled = True
set queue started = True

create queue batch
set queue batch queue_type = Execution
set queue enabled = True
set queue started = True
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with using more than one queue that can be running jobs on the same nodes. (This is the case for most queues) As a general rule, queues are meant to house jobs and not nodes, and making it so that only one queue runs jobs on nodes requires some extra work (although it is certainly possible).